# Amplifier input protection

Tags: circuit-protection

I'm working on building a voltmeter/ammeter as a hobby project. I'm pretty comfortable with power, and digital design, but I'd appreciate some input on the nuances of the analog side, specifically circuit protection.

Before I begin, I'll specify that the amplifier that I'm using is an ADA4254. It's a really cool op-amp that I absolutely love, and it has separate power supplies for the input, output, and digital. Given that the output stage and the ADC will both be powered from 5 V, I won't need protection for the ADC, so I'm really talking about protecting the inputs to the amp.

Here's a slightly simplified schematic of what I have planned:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have Schottky diodes clamping the rails to +/- 28 V. I will also note that the voltmeter is a voltage divider, this would allow Vin to be +/- 54 V before saturating.

The Ammeter is a bit more of an enigma. I still have the clamping diodes, but should I also have some additional protection? A fuse, or PTC maybe? What do all y'all think?

Comment: You should look at the schematics of well-designed DMMs such as those by Fluke and Agilent to get guidance on how to add protection to your design. Also, look on You tube for the EEVblogs on input protection.

Comment: Have you reviewed the AD4254's own internal input protection? It shows something on its block diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the error due to leakage of the Schottky diodes. It's probably too high for any decent accuracy in the case of the voltmeter.

You will get very miserable results by putting a relay contact in series with your 10m\$\Omega\$ sense resistor- the contact resistance is relatively large and quite variable in comparison. You need to sense the voltages directly across the sense resistor, which can be done a couple different ways.

It's not clear whether your currents and voltages have some relationship to the (very high) +/-28V power supply. That will affect the clamping (or lack of same). Remember the clamping just routes current into the supply, most regulators cannot sink current.

If you want to protect the sense resistors and traces you'll need something like a PTC or fuse and with that comes considerations of how fast it will open and what the maximum voltage it can break and so on. If there is a common with the current sense and your power supply you can easily damage the op-amp by applying say -100V on one of the current inputs relative to ground.

Comment: Agree. Parallel diodes for protection are risky and very temperature sensitive. Kelvin sense is a must.